# How to populate a mapped multimap?

Tags: c++, multimap, stdmap, std-pair

I have the following mapped multimap :

```
map<int, multimap<int, pair<string, string>>> modCreAlt;
```

I am trying to insert a line in it :

```
int priority = ... ;
string alertInv = ... ;
string upperAlertInv = ... ;

modCreAlt.insert(make_pair(42, make_pair(priority, make_pair(alertInv, upperAlertInv))));
```

But I get the following compilation error :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility(49):
>   error C2664: 'std::multimap<_Kty,_Ty>::multimap(const std::less<_Kty> &)' :
>   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'const std::less<_Ty> &'

----
I also tried to insert a line that way :

```
modCreAlt.insert(pair<int, multimap<int, pair<string, string>>>(42, make_pair(priority, make_pair(alertInv, upperAlertInv))));
```

And :

```
modCreAlt[42] = make_pair(priority, make_pair(alertInv, upperAlertInv));
```

which results in, respectively, the 2 following compilation errors:

> error C2665: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types

And :

> error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: At no point are you creating a multimap.

Comment: As @john says: the second element of the outermost pair must a `multimap`, not a `pair`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this perhaps (untested)

```
int priority = ... ;
string alertInv = ... ;
string upperAlertInv = ... ;

modCreAlt[42].insert(make_pair(priority, make_pair(alertInv, upperAlertInv)));
```

Using [] creates an empty multimap for you (assuming one doesn't already exist at 42).